# Compile with independent GCC and host as sysroot

Tags: linux, gcc

I have this situation: Multiple dev machines with different Ubuntu versions (16.04, 18.04, 20.04).

Each Ubuntu has it's own GCC version (16.04 > GCC5; 18.04 > GCC7)

I have built my own x86_64 GCC7 with crosstool-ng. Is it possible to use this compiler to build a codebase which does not only run on my machine but also on other dev machines with the same Ubuntu version?

Say I run 16.04, can I compile the codebase with by custom GCC and run the stuff on another 16.04 machine (of course with the same dependencies installed).

I use the following cmake toolchain:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/")
set(COMPILER_PATH "/path/to/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${COMPILER_PATH}-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${COMPILER_PATH}-g++")

set(CMAKE_C_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -B /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--rpath=/usr/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.2"
    CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE
)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-B /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--rpath=/usr/lib -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
    CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE
)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-B /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--rpath=/usr/lib -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
    CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE
)
```

The reason for all this is that I want the same compiler on all dev machines and I have the requirement that the built project runs on other machines with the same Ubuntu version.

Comment: What is the problem? If you build on a newer version it may not run on an older version, but the same version is never a problem.

Comment: I compile stuff like ROS with it and it drags me in the compilers sysroot with it's libpthread.so and so on (which are not present on another system maybe). I wanted to know if I'm doing this right and if there is any limitation with a GCC which is not natively build against my system.

Comment: You would pssibly need to somehow deploy your working version of libstdc++ and possibly libgcc to your target machines, other than that it should not matter which compiler you use.